# Select columns containing a value above a threshold

Tags: r, subset

I have the following dataset

```
df<-data.frame(c(1,2,1),c(2,1,3), c(1,3,4))
```

let say that I want to select the columns which contain a value equal or higher than 3 (i.e columns 2 and 3)

I managed to to find the logical argument using `df >= 3` and to index with `which(df>=3)` but I struggle selecting the columns.

Comment: `names(df)[colSums(df >= 3) > 0]` maybe? Or `df[colSums(df >= 3) > 0]`? Not sure what you need exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Filter` seems like a good option here:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,1), y = c(2,1,3), z = c(1,3,4))

Filter(
  function(x) max(x) >= 3,
  df
  )
```